Error in List or Table with Children only on MAC OS
I can see all the Items in the list that don’t have a parent, as expected, and I can display all those that have children. However, I encounter an error when attempting to compact anyone with children.
I have notice that the error appears when I compile in Mac OS 15.1, but not on IOS 18.1 . I neither have an error if I use OutlineGroup without a List. But Also appears if I use table.
The code bellow is the example code that you can see in the QuickHelp for List in Xcode.
struct ContentView: View {
    struct FileItem: Hashable, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
        var id: Self { self }
        var name: String
        var children: [FileItem]? = nil
        var description: String {
            switch children {
            case nil:
                return " \(name)"
            case .some(let children):
                return children.isEmpty ? " \(name)" : " \(name)"
            }
        }
    }
    let fileHierarchyData: [FileItem] = [
      FileItem(name: "users", children:
        [FileItem(name: "user1234", children:
          [FileItem(name: "Photos", children:
            [FileItem(name: "photo001.jpg"),
             FileItem(name: "photo002.jpg")]),
           FileItem(name: "Movies", children:
             [FileItem(name: "movie001.mp4")]),
              FileItem(name: "Documents", children: [])
          ]),
         FileItem(name: "newuser", children:
           [FileItem(name: "Documents", children: [])
           ])
        ]),
        FileItem(name: "private", children: nil)
    ]
    var body: some View {
        List(fileHierarchyData, children: \.children) { item in
            Text(item.description)
        }
    }
}
...

Row index -1 out of row range (numberOfRows: 9) for <SwiftUI.SwiftUIOutlineListView: 0x112087000>
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018c834ec0 __exceptionPreprocess + 176
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018c31acd8 objc_exception_throw + 88
    2   AppKit                              0x00000001903eb304 -[NSTableRowData _availableRowViewWhileUpdatingAtRow:] + 0
    3   SwiftUI                             0x00000001bb365224 $s7SwiftUI0A17UIOutlineListViewC11removeItems2at8inParent13withAnimationy10Foundation8IndexSetV_ypSgSo07NSTableeL7OptionsVtF + 1388
    4   SwiftUI                             0x00000001bb3656f8 $s7SwiftUI0A17UIOutlineListViewC11removeItems2at8inParent13withAnimationy10Foundation8IndexSetV_ypSgSo07NSTableeL7OptionsVtFTo + 252
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018c7a28b4 __invoking___ + 148
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018c7a272c -[NSInvocation invoke] + 428
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018c7d7958 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 64
    8   AppKit                              0x000000019052a110 -[_NSObjectAnimator forwardInvocation:] + 1512
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018c7a0ee4 ___forwarding___ + 964
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018c7a0a60 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96
    11  SwiftUI                             0x00000001bb37e458 $s7SwiftUI22OutlineListCoordinatorC19recursivelyDiffRows_4with2by9expandAllyAA0a9UIOutlineD4ViewC_AA0dC4ItemCAA0nD4TreeVAA14ExpansionStateOtF + 37012
    12  SwiftUI                             0x00000001bb3802b8 $s7SwiftUI22OutlineListCoordinatorC19recursivelyDiffRows_4with2by9expandAllyAA0a9UIOutlineD4ViewC_AA0dC4ItemCAA0nD4TreeVAA14ExpansionStateOtF + 44788
    13  SwiftUI                             0x00000001bb37538c $s7SwiftUI22OutlineListCoordinatorC8diffRows2of2toyAA0a9UIOutlineD4ViewC_AA0kD4TreeVtF + 120
    14  SwiftUI                             0x00000001bb36f3d4 $s7SwiftUI22OutlineListCoordinatorC6update4diff04viewD4Tree18idSelectionChanged010navigationk4SeedL0011templateRowL011transactionySb_AA04ViewdI0VS3bAA11TransactionVtFyycfU_yyXEfU_ + 220
    15  SwiftUI                             0x00000001bb369044 $s7SwiftUI22OutlineListCoordinatorC24withSelectionUpdateGuard33_BE7B171B0BEE2A9E27ED12968C3771F8LLyySS_yyXEtF + 1320
    16  SwiftUI                             0x00000001bb36f2d4 $s7SwiftUI22OutlineListCoordinatorC6update4diff04viewD4Tree18idSelectionChanged010navigationk4SeedL0011templateRowL011transactionySb_AA04ViewdI0VS3bAA11TransactionVtFyycfU_ + 708
    17  SwiftUICore                         0x00000002277cb578 $sIeg_ytIegr_TRTA + 28
    18  SwiftUICore                         0x0000000227a6d2b8 $s7SwiftUI6UpdateO15dispatchActionsyyFZ + 1236
    19  SwiftUICore                         0x0000000227a6c79c $s7SwiftUI6UpdateO3endyyFZ + 212
    20  SwiftUICore                         0x0000000227f6061c $sSo9NSRunLoopC7SwiftUIE11addObserveryyyycFZySo05CFRunbF3RefaSg_So0gB8ActivityVSvSgtcfU_Tf4ddd_n + 176
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018c7c17a8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 36
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018c7c1694 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 552
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018c7c0380 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 648
    24  HIToolbox                           0x0000000197c000cc RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
    25  HIToolbox                           0x0000000197c05d1c ReceiveNextEventCommon + 220
    26  HIToolbox                           0x0000000197c06020 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 76
    27  AppKit                              0x0000000190303650 _DPSNextEvent + 660
    28  AppKit                              0x0000000190c2a408 -[NSApplication(NSEventRouting) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 688
    29  AppKit                              0x00000001902f675c -[NSApplication run] + 480
    30  AppKit                              0x00000001902cd02c NSApplicationMain + 888
    31  SwiftUI                             0x00000001ba77045c $s7SwiftUI6runAppys5NeverOSo21NSApplicationDelegate_So11NSResponderCXcFTf4e_nAA07TestingdG0C_Tg5Tm + 160
    32  SwiftUI                             0x00000001babf4854 $s7SwiftUI6runAppys5NeverOxAA0D0RzlF + 84
    33  SwiftUI                             0x00000001baf04134 $s7SwiftUI3AppPAAE4mainyyFZ + 224
    34  Marlo SystemManagement.debug.dylib  0x0000000104c5e108 $s22Marlo_SystemManagement0a1_bC3AppV5$mainyyFZ + 40
    35  Marlo SystemManagement.debug.dylib  0x0000000104c5e1d4 __debug_main_executable_dylib_entry_point + 12
    36  dyld                                0x000000018c358274 start + 2840
)
FAULT: NSTableViewException: Row index -1 out of row range (numberOfRows: 9) for <SwiftUI.SwiftUIOutlineListView: 0x112087000>; (user info absent)`


I can't reproduce this using the given code. Is it all rows you have an issue with or only a specific? if it's the latter could you describe the problematic object?

When I have more than one objective that contains child items, I can expand any of them. However, I encounter an error when I try to collapse the child items.

Yes but I can't reproduce that so I would need more details to understand the issue.

I have notice that the error appears when I compile in Mac OS 15.1, but not on IOS 18.1 . Its seems that the error could be because of the recursive relationship

I have modify the code in order to reproduce the error

I can't reproduce this but I guess it's because my macOS and/or Xcode version is to new. Maybe you should remove SwiftData from the title (and perhaps the tags as well) since this seems to be a SwiftUI/macOS issue.

Thank you @JoakimDanielson. I have done it. What version do you have? I have  XCODE Version 16.1 beta (16B5001e) and MAC OS 15.1 Beta (24B5024e)

Oh yes, I mixed up the versions here. 15.1 is the latest so that means we are using the same versions. Strange that I can’t reproduce the problem then.

The error do not happen when I build, it happens only after compacting an expansive the items

It is solve with the update of MAC OS 15.1 Beta 3

It is solve with the update of MAC OS 15.1 Beta 3
